# getting a string from JSONobject under another JSONobject

Tags: android, json

My json  [link to json](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=26.1909614,91.7135902&radius=10000&types=&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyC0mwKn7Gai3kQmd8mieLTcq2m6GNNSXTs)

This is the code to fetch the items. I am getting the error while fetching the **photo_reference**. I know that photos is a JSONarray and inside that a JSONobject is there. The error is that it shows as no value for photos. how to get the array and how to fetch the **photo_reference** string? I'm new to JSON and this is quite difficult for me. Log cat is also shared. Thank you in advance.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                        for (int i = 0; i<array.length();i++)
                        {
                            //get the photo reference from json of google place web api
                            JSONObject o = array.getJSONObject(i);
                            Places item = new Places();

                            JSONArray photo = o.getJSONArray("photos");
                            JSONObject photos = photo.getJSONObject(0);
                            String ph_ref = photos.getString("photo_reference");


                          String id = o.getString("id");
                            String name = o.getString("name");
                            if (o.has("rating")) {
                                String rat = o.getString("rating");
                                item.setRating(rat);
                            }else{
                                item.setRating("0");
                            }
```

org.json.JSONException: No value for photos

**Logcat**

```
    org.json.JSONException: No value for photos
    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:389)
    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:584)
```

**UPDATE**

**MY SOLUTION**

```
if (o.has("photos")){
                    JSONArray photo = o.getJSONArray("photos");
                    JSONObject photos = photo.getJSONObject(0);
                    String ph_ref = photos.getString("photo_reference");
                    item.setPh_ref(ph_ref);
                    }
else
    item.setPh_ref("no photos available");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some items doesn't have the photos object in the json.

So you need to check the photo object,

```
JSONArray photo = o.getJSONArray("photos");
if(photo != null) {
   JSONObject photos = photo.getJSONObject(0);
}
```

Comment: if there is not a JSONarray photos, so what do I do? I'm using this code as this  `JSONArray photo = o.getJSONArray("photos");
                                if(photo != null) {
                                    JSONObject photos = photo.getJSONObject(0);
                                    String ph_ref = photos.getString("photo_reference");
                                    item.setPh_ref(ph_ref);
                                }
                                else
                                    item.setPh_ref("no photos present");`

Comment: anyways, got the solution. thank you so much for your time :) @bikrathor

Answer (score 1):

Some of the items just don't have "photos" inside. One of them is:

```
  {
     "geometry" : {
        "location" : {
           "lat" : 26.1744046,
           "lng" : 91.7769246
        },
        "viewport" : {
           "northeast" : {
              "lat" : 26.1757411802915,
              "lng" : 91.7782234802915
           },
           "southwest" : {
              "lat" : 26.1730432197085,
              "lng" : 91.77552551970849
           }
        }
     },
     "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/lodging-71.png",
     "id" : "f66820fca7c21cb6783fe27a996af3379ed7140e",
     "name" : "OYO 5332 Parnil Palace",
     "place_id" : "ChIJ0S48-Z5ZWjcRBXSBd8gS9q4",
     "rating" : 4.5,
     "reference" : "CmRSAAAAlzfMwWtNWJb8fFFyzsqNBxyZgbfbR4IPZLP2qQVph1NBgZqEwolpKNc7rRXBAQVFX4ph31iYvCrFM77v5QqDY8gEIWHBJMdW9vqWSiMlDCDF-_r6N4AUviMXwH6xTq64EhAFOGo0wihXKEy8GPtQayxiGhS6SNxnJ6DI58p9uwhSek-ov2pLJA",
     "scope" : "GOOGLE",
     "types" : [ "lodging", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
     "vicinity" : "Zoo Road, Zoo Tiniali, Guwahati"
  },
```